# After adding Google Play Services to project, Error: Conversion to Dalvik format failed

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a Android Project(in Eclipse IDE) which compiles and runs fine. Then i added Google Play Services Project to it as a reference.

[image]

My Java Build Path looks like this:

[image]

And:
[image]

Now when i try to run the project i see Error Message:

```
Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exceeded the max number of methods in your application. Multidex should help you: [Building Apps with Over 65K Methods](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)

Comment: llya> Thanks...I am not using gradle. How do i do multidexEnabled=true ?   Also in android manifest i already have android:name="com.myApp", how can/shud i replace it with this then: android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" ?

Comment: If you still want to use Eclipse you can enable proguard. It will remove unused methods

Comment: I am already using Proguard, but i guess its used only if i export the apk, and not when i am compiling and running in dev mode. Any hint what to do there in proguard-project.properties ? Should i be dealing with -keep class some.package there?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Proguard rules are used during apk export. There are another interesting way. Now Google Play Services divided into separate modules(https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup). So you can download only what you need (manually of course). But they are in aar-format. For using it in eclipse use this guide - https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/03/consuming-aars-eclipse.html

Comment: So using Android Studio Or introducing gradle in this Eclipse project (is that doable?) - are my other alternatives i guess. Thankyou for these useful hints - i will be trying them.

Comment: Migrated to Android Studio :). Works.